# Grub Boots into Windows 10 Only When Exiting Grub Terminal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, mbr

I have Ubuntu (18.04) and Windows 10 (May 2019 Update) installed on separate hard drives. This works, in a manner. Without entering the grub menu my system boots into Ubuntu. I can use Grub2 to boot into Windows 10. However, to do so, I have to:

1. Enter the grub menu
2. Try booting into Windows 10
3. Receive an error: "invalid EFI file path"
4. Press "escape" to enter a grub terminal
5. Type "exit" to leave the terminal (and grub)

After this, the system boots into Windows 10 successfully. My custom grub entry (/etc/grub.d/40_custom) is:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntsf
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root MY_UUID
    chainloader +1
}
```

The UUID I am using points to the larger partition of the following:

```
Device     Boot       Size    Type
/dev/sdb1  *    ...   238G    HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       ...   474M    Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

No additional information is given about these partitions when I run lsblk or blkid.

My question is, *why does this still work, and can I modify my custom grub entry so that it works when I select it, rather than after doing what I do above*?

Comment: Most probably you mixed up boot-modes (Windows is installed in legacy-mode, Ubuntu in UEFI-mode). What happens if you type `exit` in the Grub-command-line is that the boot failed and the firmware switches to the next entry in the boot-order list which is Windows in your case.

Comment: Is there a way for me to keep these mixed boot modes and avoid the error, or should one be changed to match the other?

Comment: To achieve a proper dual-boot, both systems should be installed in the same boot-mode. Examine your system first. Windows boot-mode is bound to partition-taple-type (msdos=legacy, GPT=UEFI). For Ubuntu take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111045/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-has-booted-in-uefi-mode). If boot-modes doesn't match you should convert one of the OS. But there is no harm in leaving it as it is, you can directly boot from UEFI-boot-menu without error, but maybe that's inconvenient. You can **not** modify your custom grub entry to get it done if boot-modes doesn't match.

Comment: This all makes sense, I'll see if I can get everything squared away, thanks!