# How do I upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to version 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, 20.04, lts

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS next to windows 10 and I want to update it to version 20.04 LTS, how can I do it?

Also, will there be a problem with Windows?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Artur Meinild

Comment: Can you check if Ubuntu 14.04 was installed in BIOS or UEFI mode? See [How to check if Ubuntu has booted in UEFI mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111045/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-has-booted-in-uefi-mode) Edit your question with the answer.

Comment: I agree with @sudodus that a *clean* or *fresh* install is probably best given the 6 years between a 2014-April (14.04) & 2020-April (20.04) release.  As it looks like you're using a desktop, I'd personally use an *unclean* or *upgrade via re-install* option .. ie. select existing partitions and don't format. It'll attempt to restore your additional packages in that case (if available for new release in Ubuntu repositories) I'd use it and expect everything to be great & nothing more needs to be done, if it's not *perfect* you still have the option of a *clean* install (and lost on ~15 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

In theory it might be possible to `do-release-upgrade`, but only stepwise via 16.04 and 18.04 to 20.04 (the LTS releases). It would take a lot of time is is very likely to fail somewhere.

I recommend that you **backup** your personal files (documents, pictures etc) to another drive) and after that make a **fresh installation of 20.04.x LTS** (it is at the third point release now, 20.04.3 LTS). It will probably be much faster and will give you a much cleaner system.

Comment: Ok, would you recommend a site to download it from please, I'm new to starting with linux and I have almost no personal documents but I do have some applications that I install.@sudodus

Comment: There are instructions and links at [this official web site](https://ubuntu.com/download)

Comment: Thanks, there you tell me how to do it without damaging the windows?
Is that I still work daily

Comment: @WilfredoHernandez See [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) for how to install Ubuntu without damaging Windows.

Comment: What you can do is to **make the installation into the same partition as the old Ubuntu**. (Avoid using the whole drive, because that way you overwrite Windows.) The installer will prompt you in the right direction. Please read the instructions and check carefully what you select. But there is always a risk, so in order to have peace of mind, **please backup everything that you cannot afford to lose**.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: @user68186  Thanks, i will check the link

Comment: @sudodus in principle I agree with "make the installation into the same partition as the old Ubuntu." However, this is a bit advanced method for someone new.

Comment: IMO it's better to use Disks from the live session to delete the partition currently containing Ubuntu 14.04 so there is unpartitioned free space  That way the Ubuntu installation will offer the guided installation "Alongside Windows" and Ubuntu will be installed to the unpartitioned free space